# How a java class works with it's own reference type

Tags: java, class, oop, reference

I'm fairly new to JAVA and OOP and I'm currently following an academic course where I'm learning data structures and algorithms in java.

As I was learning about implementation of linked lists I've ran into a small problem of not understanding the code how to create a node when implementing a linked list(I'm familiar with constructors and bit of recursion ).

Code of the **Node class** as follows

```
public class Node {
    public int info;
    public Node next, prev;
    public Node (int el) {
        this (el,null,null);
    }
    public Node (int el,Node n,Node p){
    info = el; next =n; prev=p;
    }
}
```

I need to know what's happening behind the scene when the code executes(especially how the line3 works)and code of the **List class** is as follows

```
public class List {
    private Node head, tail;
    public List ( ){
        head = tail = null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty( ){
        return head == null;
    }
    public void addToTail (int el) {
        if (!isEmpty ( )) {
        tail = new Node (el, null, tail);
        tail.prev.next = tail;
        } 
        else head = tail = new Node(el);
    }
    public int removeFromTail ( ){
    int el = tail.info; 
        if (head == tail)
        head = tail =null;
        else 
        { 
        tail = tail.prev; tail.next = null; 
        } 
    return el; 
    } 
}
```

(This example is given by the academy where I'm learning and I want to know how it works)

Please explain how the **Node class** works.

Comment: Do you have any specifc question ?

Comment: You could follow through with a debugger, plus read up on "doubly linked lists". There's lots of good diagrams that should explain.

Comment: Have you posted the complete code for the List class?  It makes little sense to have a doubly linked list, and then only have addToTail / removeFromTail methods.  There seems to be no mechanism for you to actually traverse the list.

Comment: I understand the theory of how linked lists are working in general but as a newbie to java I just don't have a clear idea about how the Node class is working(especially the references at the line3 of Node class)

Comment: @dave No this is just a part of List class, I did not add the whole code for the list class to make it short

Comment: Problem is the `Node` class does nothing. It is a container for 2 references to other nodes and an `int`. And you're asking how it works....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's start from the `Node` Class

```
public Node next, prev;
    public Node (int el) {
        this (el,null,null);
    }
```

Here the objects `next` and `prev` are references to the next and previous nodes to the current node (which is your current object (this))

`this (el,null,null);`

It means you are creating a node which has no previous or next node. as you pass null, null for next and previous. Its similar to creating a head as head doesn't have next and previous nodes.

When you create the head you will never change it but you will change the next of the head the time when you create the second element in your list

When you create a tail of the linked list

```
 public void addToTail (int el) {
        if (!isEmpty ( )) {
        tail = new Node (el, null, tail);
        tail.prev.next = tail;
        } 
        else head = tail = new Node(el);
    }
```

here you first create a tail Node by `tail = new Node (el, null, tail);`
And then get the previous of tail and set the next element of the prev as the tail by doing  `tail.prev.next = tail;`

Every time you add a new Node to the list you are calling `addToTail(int e1)` which updates the tail and updates the next of the old tail.

Answer (score 0):

***I need to know what's happening behind the scene when the code executes(especially how the line3 works).***

***Please explain how the Node class works.***

```
 public Node next, prev;
```

Java variables that refer to object types are *references*, not values. The fields `next` and `prev` are not Node objects. No `Node` object contains other Nodes. Instead, `next` and `prev` reference `Node` objects stored separately.

If you're coming from C or C++, you can think of these references somewhat like pointers.

**EDIT:**

If you're instead asking about the construction of linked lists in general, your Node class represents a single node, containing a single item, in a doubly linked list. In a doubly linked list, each node refers to the node before and the node after.

See this [illustration of a doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Doubly_linked_list) in this related wikipedia article.

The `List` is like a train. A `Node` is like a car in the train. The links are references between Nodes, which are similar to the coupling between train cars. The `next` and `prev` fields that you ask about are the links between nodes.

Logically, the List contains the entire train. Physically, your List references the head and tail of the train, so that it can travel over the Nodes from front-to-back, or back-to-front.

Comment: Not really an answer, just a correction on a couple of points they didn't make.

Comment: @Andy Thomas tbh this doesnt answer OPs overly broad question

Comment: @weston - The OP asked specifically about line 3, and the most common misunderstanding with beginning Java programmers is the notion that reference variables are objects. I think it is likely that this addresses the root of the OP's confusion. However, as you note, it is sufficiently broad that I could be mistaken. So, let me broaden the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the entry point of your code is a call to:

```
List list = new List();
list.addToTail(1);
list.addToTail(2);
list.removeFromTail();
```

The first line of code execute the constructor into the list class, which simply set head and tail equal to null.

The second line of code add the method addToTail, and set the variable head and tail equal to new Node(1), which invoke the constructor having one parameter only in the Node class.

The third line of code add the method addToTail, but this time the list is not empty, so the script enters in the if statement and the node that you save with  Node(2, null, tail). If you check this Node constructor with three parameters, tail (the node you added before which value was 1) will be set as the prev (previous) node associated with the current one.

The last line of code remove the 2nd node with the code tail = tail.prev; tail.next = null; and return the element you just removed.

Answer (score 0):

firstly node in java its a specific type of variable, which can do the normal work of a variable and have an other information allow her to point on an other node in your case is `public Node next, prev;`

usually node are used in list ,think like train this is why you have `addtootail` here or `removefromtail` .
in this link you find a pretty quite explanation about that.
http://www.vias.org/javacourse/chap14_02.html

Answer (score 0):

The Node class encapsulates the data, in this case an integer value named `info`.

Also, the `List` is implemented as a sequence of `Nodes`.

The reason for the `next` and `prev` values in `Node` is so that the node can be linked to its previous and next nodes in the list sequence.  The only way to access a node in the list is to traverse the list, either forwards using the `next` reference, or backwards using the `prev` reference.

Note that lists do not support random access like an array would.  To get to an element, you need to traverse the list in some direction.